# Problems with related models only in tests

Tags: django-models, pytest

I'm experiencing a relationship issue when running tests in my django project.

The error I'm encountering is this one:

```py
test setup failed
request = <SubRequest '_django_db_marker' for <Function test_epi_has_ca>>

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def _django_db_marker(request) -> None:
        """Implement the django_db marker, internal to pytest-django."""
        marker = request.node.get_closest_marker("django_db")
        if marker:
>           request.getfixturevalue("_django_db_helper")

[...]

self = <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: image>

    def resolve_related_fields(self):
        if not self.from_fields or len(self.from_fields) != len(self.to_fields):
            raise ValueError('Foreign Object from and to fields must be the same non-zero length')
        if isinstance(self.remote_field.model, str):
>           raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
E           ValueError: Related model 'myapp.Image' cannot be resolved
```

I don't get this error when I run migrations or when I run the runserver command. Only when I run the tests (pytest).

### My Structure

I have two apps with the following models:

#### myapp

```py
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Título")
    image = models.ImageField("Image", upload_to="images", blank=True, null=True)
    checksum = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def _update_md5(self):
        if self.image:
            self.checksum = hash_file(self.image)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._update_md5()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Image"
        verbose_name_plural = "Images"

class Order(models.Model):
    WAITING = "WAI"
    DELIVERED = "DEL"
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (WAITING, "Waiting"),
        (DELIVERED, "Delivered"),
    ]

    coach = models.ForeignKey(
        "myanotherapp.Coach",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="orders",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    box = models.ForeignKey(
        "myapp.Box",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="orders",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    token = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Token", max_length=6, unique=True, null=True, blank=True
    )
    quantity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Quantidade", blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Status",
        max_length=3,
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
        default=WAINTING,
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        "Created", auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True
    )
    updated = models.DateTimeField(
        "Updated", auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.coach.name
```

#### myanotherapp

```py
class Coach(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Nome", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField("E-mail", unique=True, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

### More details about the Problem

I'm encountering the above error when I add a field to the `Order` model. "Simple" (Charfield, IntegerField, etc) fields or those with a ForeignKey to `myapp` work without any issues. The error arises when I add a ForeignKey to another model in `myanotherapp`.

When a run the pytest with `--nomigrations`, the tests works.

Can someone assist in how I can further investigate this problem?